# Переместить бд MySQL в папку проекта из XAMPP папки

Tags: mysql, git, github, xampp

Есть бд MySQL которая лежит в `C:\xampp\mysql\data` нужно переместить ее в папку проекта, дабы была возможность залить на github так, чтобы человек скопировавший репозиторий смог сразу же начать работать с ней у себя локально.

Comment: dump не подойдет ?

Comment: Прямо БД на гитхаб? Может, все-таки вместо БД положить файлик с запросами для инициализации БД в нужном состоянии? Они и места меньше займут, и структура БД сразу понятна будет.

Comment: Добавлять бинарники в репозиторий - плохая идея. Скорее всего они через раз у вас будут битыми и скоро вы просто сломаете базу как у себя, так и у коллег по проекту. При этом не факт, что базу можно будет использовать, даже если ничего не побьется, особенно если вы используете InnoDB. Лучше все-таки прикладывать текстовый дамп.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** Если БД не большая, в phpmyadmin сделать експорт и файл переместить в папку проекта. Человек скопировавший репозиторий также зайдет в phpmyadmin сделает импорт БД и сможет работать у себя локально.

**Вариант 2.** Если БД побольше, сделать вышеописанные действия при помощи консоли (как это сделать оисано [здесь](https://rusadmin.biz/bloknot/import-i-eksport-bd-mysql-pri-pomoshhi-konsoli/))

**Вариант 3.** (для начинающих сложный в реализации, но хорош проектах где часто меняется структура БД) Сделать систему миграций БД. Как реализовать описано [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/121265/) и [здесь](https://webdevkin.ru/posts/backend/mysql-migrations)